# No compatible version found: mongodb@3.2.8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, connection

The error message from npm saying that the latest version of mongodb is 2.2.6?

I have tried to "npm install -g npm":
now is npm@3.10.6

Update all other things as well.

**Still not working.**

My local mongodb version is 3.2.8, the latest one.
I'm new to NodeJS. When I try to write the "package.json" file, must I write the same version as ""mongodb":"3.2.8""?

The reason why I want to install the version 3.2.8 is because I got "refused connection problem" and saw people online saying that we should have the same mongodb version as the one already installed?

In short, I probably need to "npm install" mongodb 3.2.8, but I can't because it's not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between [MongoDB the database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#aug-16-2016) and the [nodejs mongodb driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). It may be confusing since they are both called `mongodb`, but `npm install` has nothing to do with the MongoDB database itself. You are installing the nodejs driver that lets your applications use MongoDB.

The latest version of that driver is `2.2.6`. If you're starting a new project, I would remove `mongodb` from your `package.json` and just do `npm install --save mongodb`, which should add `^2.2.6` as the mongodb version which will install up to `<3.0.0` if it's not already installed.

Your version of npm has little to do with this, especially if you are using `npm 3` which is the latest major version.